# Get group by data in rails using psql in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

i am trying to get batch names group by year_name_id.

```
@data = Batch.select("year_name_id as years,array_agg(name) as names").group("year_name_id")
```

and the value of @data is

```
[#<Batch id: nil>, #<Batch id: nil>]
```

It generates query

```
SELECT year_name_id as years,array_agg(name) as names FROM "batches"  GROUP BY year_name_id
```

When i put this query in rails dbconsole.
it gives me desired output. but rails is not giving me any data.
How do i achieve this and using PGsql 9.2 and rails 4.

Comment: Short answer: `@data.first.names` will work even though the `inspect` output doesn't mention `names`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing to the right direction.